# Let $R = \mathbb{R} -\{0\}$ and the operation $*$ is $x*y = \lvert\,x\,\rvert\,y.$ Is this a group?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

This is what I have:

> 1) Associativity:
>
> > Let a,b,c $\in$ R
> >
> > a*(b*c) = a*(bc) = abc
> >
> > (a*b)*c = (ab)*c = abc
>
> 2) Identity:
>
> > a*e = a = e*a
> >
> > |a|e = a
> >
> > |e|a = a
> >
> > e = 1
>
> 3) Inverse:
>
> > a*b = e = 1
> >
> > |a|b = 1
> >
> > ab = 1
> >
> > b = $\frac1a$
>
> This is a group then. Yes, no, I'm a mess?

Comment: Just to clarify, is $R$ supposed to be set of real numbers?

Comment: Yes, that's correct.

Comment: Note that $1$ can't be the identity element, since $-1*1=|-1|1=1\neq -1$. Further, the equation $(-1)*e=-1$ forces $e=-1$. However, $1*(-1)=-1\neq 1$. Thus, there is no possible choice for the identity element, and your set is not a group under $\ast$.

Comment: By the way, you didn't provide a proof that associativity holds either. You just wrote the axioms. But are they satisfied by this operation?

Comment: @zipirovich . The proposer's reasoning  for associativity is incorrect, as $a*(b*c)=|a|\cdot |b|\cdot c,$ which is not always equal to $abc.$

Comment: In the book $A$ $ Budget$ $of$ $Trisectors$ by the mathematician Dudley Underwood,  about his encounters with mathematical cranks, he mentions one fellow who insisted that $a*b=|a|b$ was the "real" multiplication on $\mathbb R$.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

$$|-1|e=-1$$

Hence $e=-1$.

$$|1|e=1$$

Hence $e=1$.

Hence we have a contradiction.